# How to manage code push in AWS application setup?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, heroku, version-control, flask

I have been using heroku so far to deploy my Flask application where I used simple git commands like:

```
git add .
git commit -m "code changes"
git push heroku master
```

To push my code in my heroku app every time I needed some code change.

Now I have started using AWS, how can I have similar facility in AWS so that I don't have to go to the file location every time and change it and then restart apache for the changes to be reflected.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You need to look into Elastic Beanstalk, or possibly AWS CodeDeploy.

Comment: Have you tried Fabric http://www.fabfile.org/?